# How can private member variables in a superclass be accessed in a subclass?

Tags: c++

I want to do something like:

```
/*
 * Superclass.h
 *
 */

class Superclass
{
const int size;

public:
    Superclass():size(1){}
    ~Superclass(){}
};


/*
 * Subclass.h
 *
 */

#include "Superclass.h"

class Subclass : public Superclass
{

public:
    Subclass(){size;}
    ~Subclass(){}
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `protected` instead of `private`

Comment: Or add a protected method to SuperClass that returns a reference to the private member.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to access it only for construction. In that case, make a constructor which accepts the value:

```
Superclass(int size_value=1) : size(size_value) {}
```

Then use it in the subclass constructor, e.g.:

```
Subclass() : Superclass(5) {}
```